# Parsing > 30 GB file in least amount of time

Tags: python, performance, csv

My Goal: To efficiently move data from Amazon S3 to Amazon Redshift.

Basically, I am moving all CSV files on my S3 to Redshift using the below code. I parse through part of the file, build a table structure and then use the copy command to load data into redshift.

```
'''
Created on Feb 25, 2015
@author: Siddartha.Reddy
'''

import sys
from boto.s3 import connect_to_region
from boto.s3.connection import Location
import csv
import itertools
import psycopg2

''' ARGUMENTS TO PASS '''
AWS_KEY = sys.argv[1]
AWS_SECRET_KEY = sys.argv[2]
S3_DOWNLOAD_PATH = sys.argv[3]
REDSHIFT_SCHEMA = sys.argv[4]
TABLE_NAME = sys.argv[5]

UTILS = S3_DOWNLOAD_PATH.split('/')

class UTIL():

    global UTILS

    def bucket_name(self):
        self.BUCKET_NAME = UTILS[0]
        return self.BUCKET_NAME

    def path(self):
        self.PATH = ''
        offset = 0
        for value in UTILS:
            if offset == 0:
                offset += 1
            else:
                self.PATH = self.PATH + value + '/'
        return self.PATH[:-1]

def GETDATAINMEMORY():
    conn = connect_to_region(Location.USWest2,aws_access_key_id = AWS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        is_secure=False,host='s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
        )
    ut = util()
    BUCKET_NAME = ut.bucket_name()
    PATH = ut.path()
    filelist = conn.lookup(BUCKET_NAME)

    ''' Fecth part of the data from S3 '''
    for path in filelist:
        if PATH in path.name:
            DATA = path.get_contents_as_string(headers={'Range': 'bytes=%s-%s' % (0,100000000)}) 

    return DATA

def TRAVERSEDATA():
    DATA = getdatainmemory()
    CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = 'CREATE TABLE ' + REDSHIFT_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + '( '
    JUNKED_OUT = DATA[3:]
    PROCESSED_DATA = JUNKED_OUT.split('\n')
    CSV_DATA = csv.reader(PROCESSED_DATA,delimiter=',')
    COUNTER,STRING,NUMBER = 0,0,0
    COLUMN_TYPE = []

    ''' GET COLUMN NAMES AND COUNT '''
    for line in CSV_DATA:
        NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = len(line)
        COLUMN_NAMES = line
        break;

    ''' PROCESS COLUMN NAMES '''
    a = 0
    for REMOVESPACE in COLUMN_NAMES:
        TEMPHOLDER = REMOVESPACE.split(' ')
        temp1 = ''
        for x in TEMPHOLDER:
            temp1 = temp1 + x 
        COLUMN_NAMES[a] = temp1
        a = a + 1

    ''' GET COLUMN DATA TYPES '''
    # print(NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS,COLUMN_NAMES,COUNTER)
    # print(NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
    i,j,a= 0,500,0 
    while COUNTER < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS:
        for COLUMN in itertools.islice(CSV_DATA,i,j+1):
            if COLUMN[COUNTER].isdigit():
                NUMBER = NUMBER + 1
            else:
                STRING = STRING + 1
        if NUMBER == 501:
            COLUMN_TYPE.append('INTEGER')
            # print('I CAME IN')
            NUMBER = 0
        else:
            COLUMN_TYPE.append('VARCHAR(2500)')
            STRING = 0
        COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
        # print(COUNTER)

    COUNTER = 0
    ''' BUILD SCHEMA '''
    while COUNTER < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS:
        if COUNTER == 0:
            CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = CREATE_TABLE_QUERY + COLUMN_NAMES[COUNTER] + ' ' + COLUMN_TYPE[COUNTER] + ' NOT NULL,'
        else:
            CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = CREATE_TABLE_QUERY + COLUMN_NAMES[COUNTER] + ' ' + COLUMN_TYPE[COUNTER] + ' ,'
        COUNTER += 1
    CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = CREATE_TABLE_QUERY[:-2]+ ')'

    return CREATE_TABLE_QUERY

def COPY_COMMAND():
    S3_PATH = 's3://' + S3_DOWNLOAD_PATH
    COPY_COMMAND = "COPY "+REDSHIFT_SCHEMA+"."+TABLE_NAME+" from '"+S3_PATH+"' credentials 'aws_access_key_id="+AWS_KEY+";aws_secret_access_key="+AWS_SECRET_KEY+"' REGION 'us-west-2' csv delimiter ',' ignoreheader as 1 TRIMBLANKS maxerror as 500"
    return COPY_COMMAND

def S3TOREDSHIFT():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='xxx' port='5439' user='xxx' host='xxxxxx' password='xxxxx'")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+ REDSHIFT_SCHEMA + "." + TABLE_NAME)
    SCHEMA = TRAVERSEDATA()
    print(SCHEMA)
    cursor.execute(SCHEMA)
    COPY = COPY_COMMAND()
    print(COPY)
    cursor.execute(COPY)
    conn.commit()

S3TOREDSHIFT()
```

**Current Challenges:**

Challenges with creating the table structure:

1. Field lengths: Right now I am just hardcoding the VARCHAR fields to 2500. All my files are > 30gb and parsing through the whole file to calculate length of a field takes lot of processing time.
2. Determining if a column is null: I am simply hard coding the first column to NOT NULL using the COUNTER variable. (All my files have ID as first column). I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

Is there any data structure I can use? I am always interested in learning new ways to improve the performance.

Comment: I'd suggest browsing the major points of PEP-8 guidelines, otherwise every Python dev that sees your code will call you out on your code - not to mention it makes your code far easier to read.

Comment: If you care more about speed than about using Python you could check out a specialised program for loading data into PostgreSQL, [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/howto/csv.html); you'd still have to script the downloading from S3 though.

Answer (score 2):

Your capitalization convention strikes me as odd, not just for Python, but for any language I've ever used. Not only is it hard to read, but things cased LIKE_THIS are usually constants in Python, so this usage will confuse Python programmers. Many other things about your code formatting are also confusing or unconventional. Please do check out PEP-8.

Your function `traverse_data` is quite long. I'd recommend trying to split everything under `''' One of these '''` into its own function. Also note that the comment marker in Python is `#`. The syntax `''' like this '''` is for strings. Python allows you to put one of those as the first thing in a function or class, as a documentation string. You can then read documentation interactively on the command line. If the triple quoted string isn't the first thing in a function or class, it's just a string literal that never gets assigned to anything and disappears. As a personal request from me, please don't document your code like this. The performance hit is probably negligible, but it's just weird and wrong. Stick to a doc string at the start of a function or class, and regular comments for things that aren't going to be part of the code.

It's more common when you have a script you want to run from the command line to write it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # code currently inside s3_to_redshift
```